# Add row at root to JQuery treetable

Tags: jquery, treetable

I'm working with the treetable plugin and I want to add a new row on the root of the table, I use `loadBranch` and it works fine to add rows inside the tree but can't find a method to add on the root.

Answer (score 4):

You can add rows to the root by sending null as the first argument to loadBranch:

```
$("#tree").treetable("loadBranch", null, rows)
```